# How to get a pivot of a non numeric table?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

In workshop, I have a requirement of a pivot table but the columns of the aggregation dataset are non numeric. Now foundry doesnt allow aggregation over string/other values.

I need to do a conditional flag like value over few of these columns(ex: case when x then 1 else 0) and then do a sum/count of the values, hence aggregating it and displaying a pivot.

I am not preparing this data in the backend since i want the data to be updated at ontology level, if i include in dataset in the backend then i will have to wait for the pipeline build to run until the next day which is slowing the user process.

What can be the best ways to achieve it? Kindly help.

Comment: Can you share a bit more detail on the current ontology data model you have (which object types and which relevant properties are on which types) and then _conceptually_ what you need to provide in the visualization?